# Windows 7 Firewall: allow everything but block one exe from accessing anything

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-firewall

I would like to configure the Windows 7 firewall with advanced security in a way that nothing is blocked, except for one program that I want to define. So basically, the behaviour would be as if the firewall was completely turned off, but only outbound connections by one specific program (let's say ping.exe for example) is completetly blocked.

What would be the fastest way to achieve this setting?

Answer (score 1):

Set one firewall rule to allow everything, and another to deny this one program.

This will work because in Windows Firewall
[Block rules take precedence over Allow rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc755191(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).